# Return type of a class of a function inside same class

Tags: c++

Just started learning, please be gentle!
I'm working on an assignment and we were provided a .h file with all the member functions we have to complete. One of said functions has a return type of the class it's located in.

```
class A
{
    public:
        A();
        ...
        A a();
    private:
        ...
}
```

I'm implementing `A a();` with:

```
A A::a()
{
    ...
}
```

Is this the correct way of implementing this type of function? Or am I doing something completely wrong? What is the proper terminology for this type of function? And finally, how do I call it in main?

Comment: No. it should be A A::a(). because you do not need to specify where the A class is, but you do need to specify that the a() function you are defining is the A class a() function.

Comment: Sorry, typo! It's already A A::a(), thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should probably start to learn defining C++ member functions
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_class_member_functions.htm

```
class A
{
    public:
        A();
        A a();
    private:
};

A::A()
{
}

A A::a()
{
}
int main()
{
A a1;
A a2 = a1.a();
}
```